# Привязка обработчика события к методу другого окна (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, controls

Есть `TreeView` c несколькими `TreeViewItem`.

Как можно привязать события `Selected`/`Unselected` к методам, объявленным в другом окне?

Comment: Покажите какой-нибудь код к этому

Answer (score 2):

TreeViewItem.Selected += метод;

Answer (score 1):

Там должен быть `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` у объекта `TreeViewItem`. С помощью него, должно быть в основном потоке обработчика можно вызвать.

См. пример на https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx